# What is an addition sign used in url for?

Tags: javascript

Could you explain what addition signs in `"url(" + previewPic.src + ")"` are used for in the html syntax below?

```
function upDate(previewPic){
  document.getElementById('image').innerHTML=previewPic.alt;
  document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage="url(" + previewPic.src + ")";
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage="url(images.google.com/xxx)";
```

The above is the result that you will be expecting, but you dont hardcode the image source `images.google.com/xxx`. So we replace that with a variable like below, and using string concatenation to combine them.

```js
const previewPic = {
  src: 'images.google.com/xxx'
}

document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage="url(" + previewPic.src + ")";
```

And modern approach can also use string interpolation as below

```js
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage=`url(${previewPic.src})`;
```

Basically the change is that replacing `double-quote` with `back-ticks` and you don't see `+` sign anymore, you can substitute the variable with `${}` symbol